# Vue.js - Is base url of vue-router case sensitive?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a Vue.js application which use `vue-router` module.

```
export default new Router({
    base: '/CDP/V2',
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
       {
            path: '/home',
            name: 'home',
            component: HomeApp
        }
    ]
})
```

Is base `url` of vue-router case sensitive ?

And if it's yes, how can I make it  case insensitive ? I want to make "V2" part non case sensitive

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's case sensitive, you could check this [`sample code`](https://codesandbox.io/s/rjv9oj6yoq), in order to make it insensitive try the following code :

```
// Define router
const router = new VueRouter({
  base: config.basePath,
  routes,
  mode: 'history'
})

// Route case-sensitivity hotfix
if (router.mode === 'history') {
  router.history.getCurrentLocation = function() {
    let path = window.location.pathname
    let base = router.history.base

    // Removes base from path (case-insensitive)
    if (base && path.toLowerCase().indexOf(base.toLowerCase()) === 0) {
      path = path.slice(base.length)
    }

    return (path || '/') + window.location.search + window.location.hash
  }
}
```

for more details check this [`issue`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2154)